# Tables not showing very well in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I have a bootstrap modal that pops-up on-click of a button. However as soon as I added a table to this modal to display a list of items, the table shows without the button being clicked. The whole view becomes messed up. How do I solve this?

My View:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>

          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php $contacts = \Vanguard\Libraries\Utilities::getContactPersons($project->id); ?> @if(isset($contacts)) @foreach($contacts as $contact)
            <tr>
              <td>{{$contact->contact_name}}</td>
              <td>{{$contact->contact_phone_number}}</td>
              <td>{{$contact->contact_email}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach @endif

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The ?> tag is missing?

Comment: add this in your css and try. .`table-bordered td, .table-bordered th { word-break:break-all !important}`